# How to log reaction removes to another channel? Discord.py

Tags: python, logging, discord.py

I have reaction adds working perfectly fine. However, when I try to do reaction removes, nothing happens. No error messages or anything.

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_remove(reaction, user):
    message = reaction.message
    channel = message.guild.get_channel(bot_logs)
    embed=discord.Embed(title="**{} removed a reaction to a message**".format(message.author.name), description="", color=0xffa500)
    embed.add_field(name="**This is the channel the message reaction was removed in:**", value=str(message.channel), inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="**This is the message that had a reaction removed:**", value=message.content, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="**This was the emoji reaction that was removed:**", value=str(reaction), inline=True)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

This is the code I am using. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This event is only called when the message can be found in the internal message cache.

Source: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_reaction_remove

Ensure you're testing this on a message that was sent after the bot started up.

Optionally you could switch to using [on_raw_reaction_remove](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_raw_reaction_remove) since that event is called whether or not the message is in the cache. However, this event requires the [reactions gateway intent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html) in your bot.

---

After debugging and analyzing the library source code, version 1.5.0 - 1.6.0 and will return [_get_reaction_user](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/763d46cd7ab14a4b0345a69fd862de8a4eb6da10/discord/state.py#L576) as None and not fire the `on_reaction_remove` event, which seems to be a bug in Discord.py. Enabling server members intent was not helpful.
A Github issue can be found describing the behaviour: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/5867 Rolling back to version 1.4.2 can work if using on_raw_reaction_remove is not an option.

Comment: I have done that. I start the bot up, then send a message, then react. The `on_reaction_add` works perfectly fine, but the `on_reaction_remove` does nothing.

The same thing seems to happen with `on_raw_reaction_remove`